# Can I change my Palico's name?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Recently after collecting some more palicoes I decided to give them some unique names instead of just hiring "as-is", but to my dismay the name I had for it (Dr. Whiskers) was truncated to just Dr. Whiske. Is there any way I can rename them to something more... better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant. And taking a look at the name choosen by other players, there seems to be a limitation of 10 characters, and names like "Freddie Benson" and "Incredible Hulk" are being truncated to "Freddie Be" and "Incredible"

**Related stuff:**

- [Renaming Wild Palicos?](http://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/2vz40c/renaming_wild_palicos/)